# When to use SVNDepth INFINITY and when UNKNOWN?

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

What `SVNDepth` should I use:

1. to merge changes using `diffClient.doMerge` method?
2. to get status using `statusClient.doStatus` method?
3. to revert changes using `wcClient.doRevert` method?

What is the difference between `INFINITY` and `UNKNOWN` in these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What `SVNDepth` should I use ...?

It depends on the situation; how far down the directory tree do you want to merge, get status information about, or revert?

For example, if you had file changes in your target path and in a subdirectory below it, you could revert just the files changes in your target path and *not* in the subdirectory by using the depth `FILES`.  If you wanted to revert everything, use `INFINITY`.  The same applies to the other two commands.

> What is the difference between `INFINITY` and `UNKNOWN` in these cases?

The [`INFINITY` depth](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/SVNDepth.html#INFINITY) means "the target and all files and subdirectories" whereas [`UNKNOWN`](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/SVNDepth.html#UNKNOWN) is the equivalent of not specifying `--depth` on the command line, which defaults to the depth of the target specified when checking out the working copy.